# How to set quota or limits on NFS share on the client?

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 7 VM

mount.nfs version

```
mount.nfs: (linux nfs-utils 1.2.6)
```

I want to set quota on a NFS mount. The NFS server doesnt have quotas set. I installed quota, quotatool as per [this wiki](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/47/Limiting_your_users_use_of_disk_space_with_quotas)

enabled it using the below command

```
quotaon -avug
```

Then tried the nfs mount with quota option and it failed with the below error

```
mount -t nfs -o usrquota,grpquota nfs-server:/export/home/storage  /mnt/storage
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

also tried running quotaon

```
quotaon /mnt/storage/
quotaon: Mountpoint (or device) /mnt/storage not found or has no quota enabled.
```

none of them seem to work.

Is it possible to set quota for NFS share on client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the quota must be set on the NFS server, that's why `mount.nfs` does not recognize the `usrquota,grpquota` options.

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/644749/can-nfs-server-limit-the-amount-of-disk-space-that-the-nfs-client-can-use

Comment: In my case, that isn't true. I upgraded an Oracle Linux NFS client to a newer version; the mount now fails due to rejecting the `quota` option, but unupgraded clienmts mount with that option just fine.